# Sending JSON Payload through POST (PHP)

Tags: php, json, http-post, payload

I have this data. How could I send this to a specific URL and read the response.

```
 {
  "agent": {
    "name": "Minecraft",
    "version": 1
  },
  "username": "mojang account name/email",
  "password": "mojang account password",
}
```

Comment: Are you sending this data from server-side or the client-side?

Comment: It is being sent client side

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$.post` shorthand for `$.ajax` using jQuery,

Like This -

```
$.post(
 "script.php", {
 "agent": {
 "name": "Minecraft",
 "version": 1
},
 "username": "mojang account name/email",
 "password": "mojang account password",
},
function(dataReturned){ /* do something with data returned from the script */ }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AJAX` to send it as follows

- `url` - where to send your data
- `data` - what you want to send
- `error` - in case of the ajax call ends up in error
- `dataType` - what kind of data you are gonna receive
- `success` - what to after receiving response from server
- `type` - type of request

.

```
 $.ajax({
       url: 'http://example.com/sample/get_respose.php',
       data: {
           "agent": {
              "name": "Minecraft",
               "version": 1
            },
            "username": "mojang account name/email",
            "password": "mojang account password"
            },
       error: function() {
          $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
       },
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       success: function(data) {
          // use your response data
       },
       type: 'GET'
    });
```